# Wireless fast charging in car

Tags: watts, volts

For my phone I want to wirelessly charge my devices as fast as possible using the cigaret socket (Automobile auxiliary power outlet).
I bought a wireless charging pad which on the back states.

> input: 5v = 2A  output:5w
>
> input: 9v = 2A / 12V =1.5A  output:10W

Now I found a plug for the cigaret socket that says (12W/2.4A) How do I know if this makes it possible to charge at the highest speed possible?
The socket is 12 volt so I guess the interesting part is (12V =1.5A  output:10W) is 2.4A good in this case or is it to much?

*note: im absolutely clueless when talking about electricity so an eli5 explenation would be great.*

I thought `watts = volts * amps` So why does it say 12V = 1.5A  output:10W

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking for design advice without the capability to carry it out, by their own admission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right: Power [W]=Voltage[V]*Current[A]. This formula is true for input and output of a device, but the values are different in that there is a loss between input and output. (The effectively transferred power in percentage of input power is called „efficiency“.)

So it is ok that a device has less output power than input power and not possible the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

> is 2.4A good in this case or is it to much?

In general, as long as the source current rating equals or exceeds the sum of the connected loads it is fine. In the case of the lighter socket, you should check to see if there is more than one of them supplied through the same fuse. That circuit will be ok if the sum of things connected to the sockets does not exceed the fuse rating.

> I thought watts = volts * amps So why does it say 12V = 1.5A output:10W

Probably because 6 watts are lost as heat in the device. Also input current may be stated conservatively and includes momentary charging current to avoid nuisance blowing of the fuse that protects the supply circuit.